# Compare and remove a list of objects with a standard list

Tags: python

How to compare a list of objects with a standard list of IDs then remove all duplicates from the original?

Here is my problem:

I have two lists in Python.

A:

```
[<id_definitions.Wrapper object at 0x110490ba8>, <id_definitions.Wrapper object at 0x110490c18>, <id_definitions.Wrapper object at 0x110490be0>]
```

B:

```
[1, 2]
```

`A` is a list of objects, each object has the attribute called `ID`. List `B` is just a list of ID's (not objects).

I want to remove any ID's that appear in list `B` from `A`.

This is what I have tried:

```
new_list = [x for x in A if x.ID not in B]
```

My problem is that no duplicates are removed, why?

Comment: Is the `ID` attribute an integer value or a string value?

Comment: This is nowhere near enough information to help you, as it stands. Could you implement a decent `__repr__` for `Wrapper` (i.e. such that `eval(repr(instance)) == instance`), at least?

Comment: @JohnGordon O my you were right adding int(x.ID) fixed the issue!

Comment: @jonrsharpe could you explain ``__repr__`` example?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__

Comment: When you say *'My problem is that no duplicates are removed'* you mean that duplicates whose id does not show up in B are being copied to new_list and you would like to get only one of the copies?

Comment: @maccinza thats correct. However, John was spot on with my problem. I was comparing a string to an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list comprehension is right.

I am afraid it's your `x.ID` has issue. Try to `print [x.ID for x in A]` and you should be able to find the problem.